# Drupal OR query

Tags: database, drupal-7

I built this query, but I get a weird error, can anyone help me out please ?

```
$or = db_or()
            ->condition('title', 'test', 'LIKE')
            ->condition('author', 'test', 'LIKE')
            ->condition('service', 'test', 'LIKE')
            ->condition('content', 'test', 'LIKE');

    $query = db_select('magazine_articles')
            ->condition($or)
            ->execute();
    return $query;
```

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM magazine_articles magazine_articles WHERE ( (title LIKE 'test' ESCAPE '\'' at line 1: SELECT FROM {magazine_articles} magazine_articles WHERE ( (title LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_0 ESCAPE '\') OR (author LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_1 ESCAPE '\') OR (service LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_2 ESCAPE '\') OR (content LIKE :db_condition_placeholder_3 ESCAPE '\') ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => test [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => test [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => test [:db_condition_placeholder_3] => test )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified wich fields to select, try this:

```
 $or = db_or()
        ->condition('title', 'test', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('author', 'test', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('service', 'test', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('content', 'test', 'LIKE');

 $query = db_select('magazine_articles','n')->fields('n')
        ->condition($or)
        ->execute();
```

Comment: *sigh* yes, absolutely my bad. I have been looking at this for an hour and I just looked right over it. Thanks :)

Comment: @Nealv - yes, I know the feeling=)